# Payment method in Code Name One

Tags: codenameone

is there any payment method in code name one ?
Code name one home page mentioned using `zooz.com`for payment but i don't know how to do that !

PS : i'm new to codenameone

Answer (score 0):

It's called In App Purchase see this introductory blog https://www.codenameone.com/blog/intro-to-in-app-purchase.html

There is more in the [javadocs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/).